# Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value using IN on my WHERE

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, sql-update

I haven't been able to find an answer to this thus far... Maybe someone here can help.

I'm getting the following error: Error running query... ::::Error: ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '2,4'

This happens when a query is run using the mysql module in nodejs. The query is as follows:

```
 selectQ = "UPDATE usr SET pass = ?, last_updator = ?, last_update = NOW() WHERE id IN (?);"
```

I am calling it like this:

```
con.query(selectQ,[hash,lupdator,usrs], function (err, rows) {...});
```

This works fine as long as I only have one number in the usrs variable, but when I have a list of numbers (in a joined string which looks like "2,4") I get the truncation error above.

Any ideas? Thanks!

**End Result:**

Per the answer marked correct, using the prepared statement for my "IN" didn't work. I believe it would work fine if I passed a list of single-quoted strings to look up a text based datatype, but the query is instead passing the escaped INTs as text character types.

Anyhoo... I am simply verifying that all of the items within my array are numeric, and if they are I'm joining the array and passing it into the prepared query. I don't believe this leaves me exposed to injection, but feel free to correct me if I'm wrong. Here's my code:

```
for(i = 0; i < usr.length; i++){
        if(!IsNumeric(usr[i])){
            callback("Password hash failed, server side issue.",null); return;
        }
    }
    var usrs = usr.join(',');
    selectQ = "UPDATE usr SET pass = ?, last_updator = ?, last_update = NOW() WHERE id IN ("+usrs+");"
```

Comment: Prepared statements don't work like that. You have to have an `IN` clause that's got enough `?` entries for each separate parameter.

Comment: It's (usually) safe to have too many `?`, and just fill out the unused slots with nulls.

Comment: In Postgresql you can use an array operator, which is a little less messy.

Comment: Really... Alright, well I suppose that answers that. Annoying though, for sure. :( Thanks @Pointy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're passing the parameter won't give you this:

```
UPDATE usr SET pass = ?, last_updator = ?, last_update = NOW() WHERE id IN (2,4);
```

It will give you this:

```
UPDATE usr SET pass = ?, last_updator = ?, last_update = NOW() WHERE id IN ((2,4));
```

So the `2,4` becomes one single value. You will need to find another way, which probably means executing separate statements like this one:

```
UPDATE usr SET pass = ?, last_updator = ?, last_update = NOW() WHERE id = ?;
```

Also, if you are building that list dynamically, you should know that long lists of values inside `IN` statements don't scale well. And many DB servers impose limits on their size as well (MSSQL limits to 512 elements, I don't know about MySQL).

Comment: Actually, it gives you `IN ('2,4')`.

Comment: That depends. The message refers to a DOUBLE value, so I made an educated guess. But the point is that it is a single value, irrespective of type.

Comment: Separate statements are not necessary. The `IN` clause can handle as many `?` placeholders as you need: ` IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)` is fine. The OP can make the prepared query have some large number of `?` placeholders, and then pass `null` for the others. I don't know about MySQL, but other databases I've used don't seem to suffer any sort of performance degradation from that, at least nothing significant.

Comment: Also I don't think SQL Server limits `IN` clauses - I know I've built queries with 1000 or more entries in an `IN`, and that was at least 10 years ago.

Comment: So long as the column involved has an index, a big `IN` should not be a problem.

Comment: I shouldn't ever have over 100 values in my IN, so that part won't be a problem. That'd make for one heck of an index scan. Anyway, I'll add what I ended up doing to my question so others can see. Between the comments and this answer though, the original question is answered so thanks all!

Comment: @CobusKruger The error message shows a string `'2,4'`. What's happening is that the string is being converted to a `DOUBLE`, and the comma character is not valid.